# How to request mongodb atlas Database with Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, web-deployment

I need to deploy an app. I used React JS, Node JS and Mongodb atlas to do this. I tried to deploy it on Heroku but i can't reach my database wheni tried it online (work fine on local dev). What is the good syntax to reach my database with Heroku ?

Link to the website : https://teachonline.herokuapp.com/

Link to my github : https://github.com/romainbor/eteach

I tried lot of different syntax to reach my databse but it always failed.

I put the code as it is in my local dev.

```
export const register = (user_name, password, email, category, skills, description, dispatch) => {
 const data = {
     user_name, 
     password,
     description,
     email,
     category,
     skills
 };
 let myHeaders = new Headers();
 myHeaders.append("Content-type", "application/json");
 myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('tokenJWT'));
     fetch ('http://localhost:3001/user',
     {
         method:'POST',
         mode: "cors",
         headers : myHeaders,
         body: JSON.stringify(data)
     })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .catch(error => (error));



     return{
         type: "REQUEST_REGISTER",
         payload: {}
     }
};
```

my package.json in my client folder

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

If i remove the proxy line, my app is online but i never reach my database, so my app is unusable.
If i put the proxy line i got "Invalid Host header"

So i missunderstand something but i don't know what exactly

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that seem wrong to me.

1) You are calling `fetch ('http://localhost:3001/user',` you can't know on which port your app will run on the production server so I guess you should instead just `fetch ('/`.

1) In your index.js (in the server dir, I found on your github) you define on line 13 `const PORT = 5000;` but this is the same issue cause you don't know the port on production so you can change this to `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;` this way it checks for the servers' PORT in env variables and if it can't find it (for example on your local machine) only then uses 5000.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, first thanks for your reply.
I tried what you say but i go an error with my client now : "something is already running on port 12345".
I missunderstand something about this i think ... but i don't know what exactly